# detectar el cambio de valor de un elemento , Hecho desde un evento otro elemento

Tags: javascript, html

es posible detectar el cambio de valor de un elemento INPUT2, Hecho desde un evento de elemento INPUT1???

```js
function f1(){
    document.getElementById('input2').value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
}

function f2(){
  alert('input2 cambiado');
}
```

```html
 <input class="controlevents" id="input1" type="text" onkeyup="f1()" />
 <input class="controlevents" id="input2" type="text" onchange="f2()" />
```

es decir, si escribo en INPUT1, se ejecuta la funcion f1 sin problema y cambia el value de INPUT2, pero al cambiar el value del INPUT2 la funcion f2 no se ejecuta.

Saludos

Comment: onchange requiere que cambies el focus es decir si lo cambias y das click fuera del elemento input2 saltara la alerta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías llamar a la función `onchange` que tiene asociada el elemento con ID **input2**.

```html
<input class="controlevents" id="input1" type="text" onkeyup="f1()" />
<input class="controlevents" id="input2" type="text" onchange="f2()" />

<script>
function f1() {
  let input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
  
  input2.value = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  input2.onchange();
}

function f2() {
  alert('input2 cambiado');
}
</script>
```

Comment: perfecto, solucionado muchas gracias